# smooter animation with JavaScript requestanimationframe

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I am writing Javascript slider using requestAnimationFrame function. I code some effects of slider seperately from the core for the purpose of to be easy, and finally i'll combine them together. Below I coded simple animation, it works without problem. But there is a problem it is not smoother enough like CSS slider stated below.

[this is a link](http://codepen.io/Gurbanov/pen/NRAAQr)

But i want let the animation be like slider below. This slider is done in CSS. Below is its link.

[`CSS slider`](http://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/ZpWRjv)

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Animations with javascript are not smooth. It's better with CSS. Javascript animations will be smoother only on powerful machines.

Comment: you'll need some easing algorithms too

Comment: like this---easeOutQuint: function (t) { return 1+(--t)*t*t*t*t }???